# Updating complete Gantt view after change occurs

Tags: sharepoint-foundation

I have the following scenario.

A User change the Enddate from a task ( in the Gantt view), 
after that a programmed Event receiver fires up and changes the Enddates from the predeccors.

This works fine.

But in the frontend I see only the field updated, wich was changed from the user.

Is it possible to refresh the whole Gantt from Codebehind or a javascript postback or s.th.?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found my Solution

The right method is the following

```
function OnPropertyChanged(propChangedArgs, bEntryRowPlayback)
```

In that there are some sub methods

I know that I have an autocalculated column that will be refreshed after changes.

So I react on these column (called “duration”). I wrote this simple script snippled

```
if (propChangedArgs.fieldKey===”Duration”){
location.href=location.href;  // refresh me
}
```

It checks if the current column is “Duration”. If this is true, the page will be automatically refrshed.

That works great, but it is not the good MS way. So I take it out and worte a custom script method an put that into an Content Editor Webpart (CEWP).

This is a cutout with the main information from my blogpost.

http://sharepointsascha.tumblr.com/post/79153490652/autorefresh-sharepoint-gantt-view

Comment: Please add the details here, driving traffic to your blog is frowned upon and your answer will be of little help if the link breaks

Comment: It's done. Sorry on my iPad I couldn't wrote so much text ;)

Answer (score 0):

You can also set your Event Receiver to Synchronous mode, which will not return and refresh the display until after all the fields are updated.

Comment: The Problem by this is, that the Gantt view is completely in javascript. It performs a refresh. but only from the current row. Not for the complete grid, because I do some calculations that change other tasks in the gantt view.